# why same material can make different effect on a model

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wonder why one material can have different effect on the different part of one model .
For example , a material can make up the horror face of the zombie and also the limbs of it .

Please answer with full explaination ,your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping).

Answer (score 1):

The keyword should be shader effect, instead of material.
In general, you need to write a shader which support multiple textures.

Also, based on UV position, you can adjust different part of your 3D model. It could be color, texture, vertex.

If you are interested in this topic in Unity3D, you have to learn basic of writing a shader.